# Why is it impossible to hold these probability beliefs?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Why is it impossible to hold these probability beliefs?

\begin{align*}
P(a) & = 0.3 & P(a \land b) & = 0 \\
P(b) & = 0.4 & P(a \vee b) & = 0.8
\end{align*}

I know that you cant have $P(a)+P(b)$ be less than $P(a \vee b)$. But is that the only reason why these are impossible?

Comment: In principle, yes, we must have $P(a\lor b)\le P(a)+P(b)$. We can at most be more precise by saying that $P(a\lor b)+P(a\land b)=P(a)+P(b)$

Comment: More particularly, $P(a \vee b) = P(a) + P(b) - P(a \land b) = 0.3 + 0.4 - 0 = 0.7 \neq 0.8$.

Comment: One reason for something being impossible is usually enough.

Comment: As those of us who have taught probability know all too well, it is perfectly possible to hold false and/or inconsistent beliefs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that it's against the rules of probability 
$$P(a) + P(b) = P(a\vee b) + P(a\wedge b)$$
It's a theorem end of story.

That's maths, in real life it's more a question of what probability means and why you should believe the rules, which is philosophically quite deep.
There's an easy answer though, if you believe the above then I can con you out of money.

Suppose you believe the above now I offer you 31p on the condition that you give me £1 if $a$ happens.  As the probability of $a$ is $0.3$ you happily accept my offer looking forward to a 1p profit.

Next I offer you 41p on the condition that you pay me £1 if $b$ happens.  The probability's $0.4$ so again you make a profit of 1p.

Finally I say I'll pay you a pound if either $a$ or $b$ happens, not for free of course, I want 79p from you now.  $P(a\vee b) = 0.8$ another 1p profit for you.

So, you've gone away thinking you've made 3p expected profit. In fact, I've paid you 72p and claimed 79p but whatever happens I can't loose money, if $a$ or $b$ happen I have to pay you £1, but you have to pay me at least £1 (maybe £2).

Now as you think you've got a good deal I can offer you the same thing again, taking 7p off you each time, I can't loose but if we keep it up for long enough I'll take all your money and you'll still think you've got a good deal.

It turns out all the basic rules of probability have equivalent "Dutch books" like the one above. So in a sense you have to believe them because if you don't you can end up acting irrationally.

Comment: by 31p do you mean 31 pounds?

Comment: and also did you mean to write P(a OR b)=0.8?

Comment: I did mean a OR b, but 31p = £0.31.   So if $P(a) = 0.3$   then the promise of £1, conditional on the event $a$,  is "worth" £0.3 = 30p.  So if I offer you 31p to make me that promise you should accept my offer.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer 1*: What other reason do you need?

*Answer 2*: What happens when you test it several times? Statistically, **a** should happen 3 out of 10 times and **b** should happen 4 out of 10 times. Now think about **a or b**.

Comment: So thats the only reason? I thought there would be multiple reasons. In my textbook it talks about how there is some "intense research" being done to solve the issue, and i dont know what exactly they debating/researching

Comment: "Intense research"? Wow. What is the book already?

Comment: @Did  AI a modern approach

Comment: [This](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)? And where is the "intense research" mentioned?

Comment: @Did yea. in the chapter called quantifying uncertainty, page 497. It says intense debate, not research.

Comment: Two oddities: 1. The text seems to allude to "debates" long ended as if these were contemporary. 2. It refers repeatedly to "alternative approaches" to "the use of probabilities", but explains none in details (that is, in the pages nearby, perhaps elsewhere in the book?).